# Whats the difference between APP ID and API key?

Tags: javascript, browser, facebook-javascript-sdk

Can anyone please tell me whats the exact difference between App id and api key? I am basically trying to post the score of a game on facebook with the click of a button (game works offline on browsers) . This is the basic code meant for posting as mentioned in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Great Website</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
  </script>
  <script>
     FB.init({ 
        appId:'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', cookie:true, 
        status:true, xfbml:true 
     });

     FB.ui({ method: 'feed', 
        message: 'Facebook for Websites is super-cool'});
  </script>
 </body>
```

(note: i replaced 'XXX..' with a 15 digit code what I have). This particular code throws an error something like this 'An error occurred with TestAndroid. Please try again later.' Can anyone help me to debugg this. Thanks.

Comment: There is no difference.  View your app settings page an you will see they are the same thing: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly. Theres no difference beetween this variable. As You may know (or not) APP ID name was used before Facebook made OAuth-authentication. Now they're trying to use API Key name, because since OAuth is using, APP ID name is obsolete :)